# Separating vars in ansible while running on localhost

Tags: ansible

I have various types of servers which can be divided into groups ex A, B, and C. Each of these groups will have their own variable sets.

Now I will be executing playbook on localhost in each of these servers using `ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local playbook.yml` command. Now I want to access variables specific to the group to which server belongs.

In the playbook if I set `hosts: A` and run the above command then I get the error `[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: A` and if I put `hosts: localhost` or something else then I get a `variable undefined error`.

It would be really helpful if someone can update me what might be the solution where I can run playbook on localhost and at the same time access group vars belonging to server's group.

Please note that I can only run playbook using localhost and that is a constraint.

Comment: `variable undefined error` means some variable is undefined.　・　"*Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*"

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. That error is coming because I set `hosts: localhost` while variables are defined for group A.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `-c local` Ansible will execute tasks on your controller in any case.

If you use `-l serverA` Ansible will execute tasks for `serverA` only.

So you can make inventory like this:

```
[groupA]
serverA

[groupB]
serverB
```

In your playbook:

```
hosts: all
```

And execute like this:

```
ansible-playbook -l serverA -c local playbook.yml
```

this will take vars from `serverA/groupA` and execute tasks locally on your controller.